# Crear thumbnails en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de DJango y necesito crear thumbnails automaticos:
este es mi codigo

HTML:

```
    <div class="d-flex container-fluid">
        <div style="max-height: 25rem;" class="container-video w-100 container-fluid">
            <video src="../static\test/1.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="video" name="../static\test/" preload controls poster="{% static 'img/video.png' %}" class="bg-dark m-auto">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div style="max-height: 25rem;" class="w-100 border-3 border-dark container-cards">
            <ul class="scroll-bar overflow-auto pt-1 ps-1" style="height: 100%;">
                <div class="cards">
                    <a style="width: 100%;height: 5rem;" class="boton-video-link d-flex flex-row p-0 btn text-light" onclick="createvideo('1.mp4'),createthumb('1.mp4');">
                        <div id="nombre_video" style="width:5rem;min-width: 5rem;" class="h-100 d-flex justify-content-center overflow-hidden">
                            <canvas for="nombre_video"></canvas>
                            <img class="img-thumbnails" src="{% static 'img/video.png' %}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="overflow-hidden h-100 p-2 fw-bold">
                            <p>Video 1</p>
                            <p for="nombre_video"></p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

script:

```
    namevideo = document.getElementById("video").getAttribute('name')
    
    ///FUNCION PARA QUE EL VIDEO SE REPRODUZCA CUANDO HAGO CLICK EN UNA TARGETA
    function createvideo(ax){
        all = namevideo + ax;
        document.getElementById("video").setAttribute('src',all);
    }
    ///FUNCION PARA MOSTRAR LA DURACION DE CADA VIDEO
    function secondsToString(seconds) {
        var hour = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
        hour = (hour < 10)? '0' + hour : hour;
        var minute = Math.floor((seconds / 60) % 60);
        minute = (minute < 10)? '0' + minute : minute;
        var second = seconds % 60;
        second = (second < 10)? '0' + second : second;
        return hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second.toString().charAt(0)+second.toString().charAt(1);
    }
    
    ///FUNCION PARA CREAR THUMBS
    function createthumb(ax){
        dir = namevideo + ax;
        var video = document.createElement('video');
        video.setAttribute('src',dir);
        video.load();
        var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas[for ='" + ax + "']");
    
        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
            canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
            canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
            duracion = "Duracion : " + secondsToString(video.duration);
            document.querySelector("p[for = '" + ax + "']").append(duracion); 
        });
        document.querySelector("video").addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
            canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute('src', canvas.toDataURL());
            img.setAttribute('class','img-thumbnails');
            document.getElementById(ax).append(img);
        });
    }
```

cada vez que hago click en una tarjeta () el  carga la URL de un video y se ejecuta, pero lo que necesito es que esa tarjeta tenga interno un thumbs creado con la funcion de js (createthumb), osea cuando cargo la pagina automaticamente se crea un thumb en cada tarjeta con cada video asociado